# angular 9 websocket get connection status

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wrote simple websocket connection on angular 9 .
this is example code :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {webSocket} from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import {delay, retryWhen} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebSocketService {
  private host = 'ws://localhost:8080/test';
  private isConnected = false;

  private ws = webSocket({
    url: this.host,
    openObserver: {
      next: () => this.isConnected = true
    },
    closeObserver: {
      next: () => this.isConnected = false
    }
  });

  constructor() {
    this.ws
      .pipe(
        retryWhen(e => {
          delay(400);
          return e;
        })
      ).subscribe();

    console.log('Connection status: ' + this.isConnected);
  }

  public sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.ws.next(msg);
  }
}
```

with this code i can send message without any problem .
I want to check connection status but `isConnected` always return false !
How can fix this problem ?

Comment: try it on the constructor
`this.ws.pipe(
  retryWhen(e => {
    delay(400);
    return e;
    })
 ).subscribe(_ => console.log('Connection status: ' + this.isConnected));`